# Need help installing fork cms 4.5.0 on apache 2.4.25

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, content-management-system

I am trying to install fork cms on my laptop. I checked the system requirements for all php extensions and made changes to apache configuration including:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

and

AllowOverride FileInfo in 3 separate locations.

To be honest I am new to this so I need to do more reading as to the implications of those changes. 
The fork cms files are in the root of my server, which is htdocs in xampp. 
When I type localhost/forkcms I get the access forbidden error 403.
I am unsure what else I need to change in order to allow for the installation to begin.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your vhost.conf file you'll have to add this and replace directory with path to your project's root

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectroot">
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

After doing that and it still not works, try setting the debug flag on within index.php (Root)

```
// get environment and debug mode from environment variables
$env = getenv('FORK_ENV') ?: 'prod';
$debug = getenv('FORK_DEBUG') === '1';

$env = 'dev';
$debug = 1;
```

If that still doesn't work, try and clear the cache by using bash capable command like too.

```
php app/console cache:clear
cd tools && ./remove_cache
```

You might have some permission issues as you're working with Windows.

```
chmod -R 777 app/console
chmod -R 777 app/logs
chmod -R 777 app/cache
chmod -R 777 src/Frontend/Cache
chmod -R 777 src/Frontend/Files
chmod -R 777 src/Backend/Cache
```

This should do the trick, if it doesn't help just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had trouble getting forkcms to install on localhost with xampp.

I tried many answers, but the final solution was to open **httpd.conf** and change

`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"` to `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs<Name of my project>"`

This changes the default root to the directory where you installed forkcms, it should be changed back after you finish your work on forkcms.

Another solution might be to rename the **htdocs** folder to something else, make another **htdocs** folder and put the root files from forkcms in there.

I also had to enable the intl plugin from the **php.ini** file by removing the `;` from `;extension=php_intl.dll`